# Negative value error "could not convert string to float:"

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello im getting "could not convert string to float:" error.
I think I need to use the replace command. I am a novice. That's why I couldn't edit the code. :)

```
def net_both(stoploss_value, takeprofit_value, wait):
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "additional_percent_value")))
    try:
        time.sleep(.5)
        check = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("additional_percent_value")[0]
        check.find_element_by_xpath('./span[contains(@class, "neg")]')
        negative = True
    except NoSuchElementException:
        negative = False

    if negative:
        net_profit = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("additional_percent_value")[0].text.split(" %")
        net_value = -float(net_profit[0].replace('−', ''))
        profits.update({-net_value: ["Stoploss:", stoploss_value, "Take Profit:", takeprofit_value]})
        print(colored(f'Net Profit: -{net_value}% --> Stoploss: {stoploss_value}, Take Profit: {takeprofit_value}', 'red'))
```

Comment: selenium.webdriver. library.

Comment: In your own words, where the code says `float(net_profit[0].replace('−', ''))`, *why should* that compute a sensible result? What do you expect `net_profit` to contain? What do you expect `net_profit[0]` to contain? What do you expect `net_profit[0].replace('−', '')` to contain?

Comment: Also, please read the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure your code appears here exactly as you have it. Indentation is crucial in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Try to:

- remove `.text.split(' %')`
- replace `-float(net_profit[0])` by `float(net_profit.replace('−', '-').rstrip('%'))`

```
if negative:
    net_profit = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("additional_percent_value")[0]
    net_value = float(net_profit.replace('−', '-').rstrip('%'))
    profits.update({-net_value: ["Stoploss:", stoploss_value, "Take Profit:", takeprofit_value]})
```

Comment: line 46, in net_both
    net_value = -float(net_profit)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '−17.18 '

Comment: It's because `−` is not the same as `-`. Check https://www.codetable.net/decimal/8722

Comment: It should work now. Can you check it? Does it work?